# Django Template comparison inside a loop

Tags: django, templates, comparison

I need compare the values of a Model with the result of an aggregate in  my template.
like a :

```
{% for valor in valores %}
    {{ valor.quantidade }}
{% endfor %}
results of my loop

{{ total.total_quantidade }}
this is the result of my Aggregate
```

How i can make the comparison of this values?

List of results of my `{% for valor ... %}`

```
1000
2000
3000
```

result of my aggregate

```
1500
```

`{% if total.quantidade_total >= valor.quantidade %}` shows the equivalent value ..and so on, if smaller shows another value

how can i proceed?

Answer (score 3):

What's the difficulty?

```
{% for valor in valores %}
    {% if total.quantidade_total >= valor.quantidade %}
        Do something
    {% else %}
        Do something else
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```